# What has happened to account de-association?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

According to [an official press release](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association) account de-association should be a deployed feature.

However a `de-associate` button is nowhere to be found:

[image]

What has happened to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to project costanza wallet being deployed (all of your users are on the same account, at a network level), association is no longer necessary from a user point of view.

We're still doing the (sometimes painful) association dance automatically to support some legacy usages at the moment (like Chat and API - for user GUIDs), but even that will go away in the future.

Comment: What is the procedure for deleting a user on a specific site, then?

Comment: @Saul - You can put "delete me" in the user name or about me field and then flag one of your posts instructing a moderator to delete it...or email team@stackexchange.com with the same request.  Or, if you have *no* activity, there's a self "delete" link beside edit.